# How to apply sequentinal MSE model to data that is not binary?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, sequential-pattern-mining

I have been using this model with binary data to predict likely hood of play from this [guide](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/tensorflow-and-keras-a-beginners-tutorial-by-a-beginner-abd4c90f814f).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy  as np
import pandas as pd



model = keras.Sequential()

input_layer = keras.layers.Dense(3, input_shape=[3], activation='tanh')
model.add(input_layer)

output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
model.add(output_layer)

gd = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)

model.compile(optimizer=gd, loss='mse')

sess = tf.Session()  #NEW LINE

training_x = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [-1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, 1, 1]])
training_y = np.array([[0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [1],[0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [0]])



init_op = tf.initializers.global_variables()


sess.run(init_op)  #NEW LINE

model.fit(training_x, training_y, epochs=1000, steps_per_epoch = 10)


text_x = np.array([[1, 0, 0]])
test_y = model.predict(text_x, verbose=0, steps=1)

print(test_y)
```

All the current data is binary and model works with binary, is there any model or way to convert non-binary data to binary predict likelihood of `product_sold` in the below data set?

dataset:

```
number_infants    cost_of_infants     estimated_cost_infants    product_sold
5                     1000               2000                         0
6                     8919               1222                         1
7                     10000              891                          1

product_sold
1 = yes
0 = no
```